# Word for a person being used

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is being used. I want a noun to describe this person, not a verb or or adjective.  Maybe like a pushover.

Comment: I disagree with this being marked as duplicate.  Being used and being picked on are different things.  The up-voted answer (full disclosure, my answer), sucker and patsy, do not describe someone being picked on.

Answer (score 29):

A [pawn](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pawn) can be somebody who's being pushed around, or used for somebody else's benefit, often without being aware of it:

> - a person, group, etc, manipulated by another

Comment: Good answer. It goes to show, the right word really depends on the way the person is being used.  I think of pawn in the context of political intrigue.

Answer (score 18):

*Patsy*.  Although this is specific to accountability being transferred unfairly, as in someone taking the blame for someone else's crime.

*Sucker*. This is pretty good for many cases.

Neither apply to a romantic relationship, though.  If that's what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 for sucker. That's the most common way to describe such a person.

Comment: Patsy was the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 15):

Perhaps *doormat*, as in "(s)he's walking all over you".

Comment: My first and instinctive thought, too.

Answer (score 7):

A tool--one that is used or manipulated by another. e.g. 'Anastasius was a willing tool of the Roman Empire.

Comment: +1 Not all uses of 'being used' need to be negative.

Comment: Your comment is not inconsistent with my answer.

Comment: @user3847 (He preceded with +1 to show agreement; and I agree as well... +1!)

Comment: I think the word "tool" more often implies a negative interpretation.  A similar word with a more positive spin might be "instrument."  I.e. "He was an instrument of the Lord."

Comment: "Tool" when applied to a person may also be a derogatory term that refers to a slang word for "penis". So be careful.

Answer (score 6):

There is ***[cat's-paw](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cat%27s-paw)*** as a noun. It has the sense of being exploited.

> A person used by another as a dupe or tool.

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=CAT) of this term suggests an interesting story about how a monkey tricks a cat by using the cat:

> Cat's paw (1769, but cat's foot in the same sense, 1590s) refers to old folk tale in which the monkey tricks the cat into pawing chestnuts from a fire; the monkey gets the nuts, the cat gets a burnt paw.

---

As you can see in the above definition of *cat's-paw*, you can use ***dupe*** and ***tool*** also depending on the context.

Answer (score 2):

According to context, also a [scapegoat](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Scapegoat) may fit your description:

> - a person or group made to bear the blame for others or to suffer in their place.

Origin:

> - (Bible) Old Testament a goat used in the ritual of Yom Kippur (Leviticus 16); it was symbolically laden with the sins of the Israelites and sent into the wilderness to be destroyed.

Source: Collins Dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Guinea pig- It is person or thing used as a subject for experiment or it can be someone subject of research, experimentation, or testing.

Colloquially, we use guinea pig as someone we used to test or try something, or to get through a circumstance using them as expedient.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen *fall-guy* or *victim* among the answers yet.

I agree with several others here that it totally depends on context what the best word would be.

Answer (score 0):

***host*** may  be appropriate and the user(s) would then be ***pest(s)***.

Answer (score 0):

'The fallguy'--40's film noir slang for one who is set up to take the rap for a crime. I suppose the term could be extended to persons becoming a 'scapegoat' for a failure in business dealings. Sam Spade's closing remark to Brigid O'Shaugnessy in the Maltese Falcon: 'You're taking the fall.'

Answer (score -3):

Employee
to make this post at least 30 characters long, I shall say it again.  Employee.

Comment: Instead of referring to the 30 char limit you could insert a dictionary definition which seconds your statement.